# Web2py - multiple options checkbox implementation

Tags: web2py

I am trying to implement a form where each field has multiple options and it has to be rows of checkboxes.  I would like to display this form with field names in row header and checkbox options in the corresponding row.  I will also need help with database table implementation as well.  Any help will be appreciated.  I am new to web2py.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? It sounds like you want a data model with booleans:

(in models/???.py -- make sure it executes after db.py and that you've defined a DB)

```
db.define_table('table_name', 
   Field('SomeFieldA', 'boolean')
   Field('SomeFieldB', 'boolean')
   Field('SomeFieldC', 'boolean')
   Field('SomeFieldD', 'boolean')
   ... etc ...
)
```

You will probably have to implement a custom form to get the layout you want, as I can't think of an out-of-the-box way to do it.

Read about [custom forms here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#Custom-forms).

You'll need to start with something like:

```
<table>
{{=form.custom.begin}}
  <thead>
    <tr>
    {{ #loop over form field labels... something like:
      for field in form.fields: }}
      <th>{{=field.label}}</th>
    {{ pass }}
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
    {{for field in form.fields: }}
      <td>{{  =form.custom.widget[field]  }}</td>
      {{ # or directly access it without a loop with form.custom.widget.SomeFieldA }}
    {{ pass }}
    </tr>
  </tbody>      

  {{=form.custom.submit}}
{{=form.custom.end}} 
</table>
```

Note that I haven't tested ANY of this code, and I may be accessing the form fields and label incorrectly. If you need to pre-populate the form, do so in the controller. The link above for custom forms also discusses prepopulating.